# php strtotime strange behavior

Tags: php, timezone, strtotime

I'm currently working with timezone for a php app.

I found that strtotime seems to not have a coherent behavior.
This example highlight what I'am talking about :

```
var_dump("strtotime('now'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(strtotime('now'));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
var_dump(strtotime('now'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
var_dump(strtotime('now'));

var_dump("strtotime('now UTC'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(strtotime('now UTC'));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
var_dump(strtotime('now UTC'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
var_dump(strtotime('now UTC'));

var_dump("strtotime('today'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(strtotime('today'));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
var_dump(strtotime('today'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
var_dump(strtotime('today'));

var_dump("strtotime('today UTC'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
var_dump(strtotime('today UTC'));
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
var_dump(strtotime('today UTC'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
var_dump(strtotime('today UTC'));
```

Results in :

```
string 'strtotime('now'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York'
int 1404821878
int 1404821878
int 1404821878
string 'strtotime('now UTC'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York'
int 1404821878
int 1404829078
int 1404807478
string 'strtotime('today'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York'
int 1404777600
int 1404770400
int 1404792000
string 'strtotime('today UTC'), UTC, Europe/Paris and America/New_York'
int 1404777600
int 1404777600
int 1404777600
```

`strtotime('foo UTC')` should always returns an UTC timestamp, whatever `date_default_timezone_get()` returns.

It works well for `strotime('today UTC')` which returns in this example always `1404777600`.
Also, `strtotime('today')` returns as expected a different timestamp depending on which timezone is set.

But it has the opposite behavior when calling `strtotime('now UTC')`, which returns differents timestamp function of timezones set, and returns always `1404821878` when calling `strtotime('now')`.

Is that a bug or did I misunderstand something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime('now UTC')` takes the current time in your timezone, interprets it as a local time UTC and returns the result. I.e.:

```
strtotime('now UTC') → strtotime('2014-07-08 14:35:00 UTC') → result
```

This conversion does not happen if you leave out "UTC" because "now" is "now", anywhere in the world.

As an aside: I'd never rely on `strtotime`'s more esoteric automagic time math anyway, since it's often not even well defined. `strtotime` returns a timestamp which is accurate to the second. In that context, what does "today" mean exactly? What does "now UTC" mean exactly? What does "+1 month" mean exactly? `strtotime` is great for converting a *complete* timestamp string like `2014-07-08 14:35:00 Europe/Berlin` into a UNIX timestamp. Anything more ambiguous than that typically has an undefined result anyway.